# Shiro using spring gives " Shiro INI configuration was either not found or discovered to be empty/unconfigured."

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I was able to get shiro running with shiro.ini and spring but I want to use shiro annotations and so i was trying to go for shiro-spring without ini file. but this is giving me hard time, 
Error:

org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Shiro INI configuration was either not found or discovered to be empty/unconfigured.
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:87)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:226)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:138)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Apr 09, 2017 4:15:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

Code:     Spring config:

```
package com.studentshare.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.studentshare")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcRealm myRealm() {
        JdbcRealm jdbcRealm = new JdbcRealm();
        jdbcRealm.setAuthenticationQuery("select password from unishare.users where user_name = ?");
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setUser("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("unishare");

        jdbcRealm.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(new HashedCredentialsMatcher());
        return jdbcRealm;
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(@Autowired JdbcRealm myRealm) {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(myRealm);
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter myAuthBasic(){
        return new BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean ShiroFilter(@Autowired DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager,@Autowired BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter myAuthBasic) {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
        filters.put("myAuthcBasic", myAuthBasic);
        shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

        /*Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new HashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/", "authcBasic");*/
        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitions("/ = myAuthcBasic");//p(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return shiroFilter;
    }

    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    @Bean
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }



}
```

Web configuration:

```
package com.studentshare.config;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener;
import org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new ShiroFilter() };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(EnvironmentLoaderListener.class);
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> shiroDispatchers = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD,
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR);

        FilterRegistration shiroFilter = servletContext.addFilter("ShiroFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        shiroFilter.setInitParameter("targetFilterLifecycle", "true");
        shiroFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(shiroDispatchers, false,
                "/*");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 1.4+ release, the Spring integration has been updated (for Spring, and Spring Boot).

But for your specific problem, it looks like you are trying to use a the EnvironmentLoaderListener. When using Spring, you will need to let Spring handle the lifecycle of loading your components.

For an example see: https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.3.x/samples/spring-hibernate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: The use of the EnvironmentLoaderListener was what caused this problem for me.